# Close ifreame using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How do i close the `iframe` using `javascript`.I found some method to do that using

`window.parent.close();`

but this method close the whole tab.But what I need is only close the `iframe`.Any one got a solution for that??

Comment: From main window or from iframe?

Comment: want to remove iframe from main window.But still i need to keep main window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iframe isn't a window, it can't be closed. You may [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) it using

```
$(theIFrame).hide();
```

or [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it if you won't use it again :

```
$(theIFrame).remove();
```

---

If you want to hide or remove the iframe from a script **inside** the iframe document, you must get the relevant element first. You can do this :

```
    var iframe = $(parent.document).find('iframe').filter(function() {
        return this.src==location.href;
    });
    iframe.remove();
```

If you don't do this from the iframe, you **should** have some kind of reference. Or you may do it indiscriminately as

```
$('iframe').remove();
```

Comment: but i dont know abut the id of the iframe.Is it can hide the parent window of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You cant close an iframe.

you must remove the node with `elem.removeChild(elem_iframe)`